# Style childmost hovered element

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to recreate something like the chrome developer tools element inspector, wherein I can get the element that's currently being hovered.

I want to add a hover effect to every element on the page sort of like this:

```css
:hover {
    border: 1px solid blue !important;
}
```

But the problem is that it'll show me every single parent element up until that point since they are also being hovered.

```css
:hover {
  border: 1px solid blue !important;
}
```

```html
<div>1  
    <div>1.1 
        <div>1.1.1</div>
        <div>1.1.2</div>
    </div>
    <div>1.2 
        <div>1.2.1</div>
        <div>1.2.2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Since there is no parent selector, I can't check to omit elements that have children that have the `:hover` property.

I can't use `:last-child` as the lowest level element may be a grandchild.

Any ways to style just the child-most element being hovered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution using jQuery's`mouseenter`/`mouseleave`:

```js
$("*")
    .mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).addClass("hovered");
        $(this).parents(".hovered").removeClass("hovered"); 
    })
    .mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("hovered");
        $(this).closest(":hover").addClass("hovered");
     });
```

```css
.hovered {
    border: 1px solid blue !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>1  
    <div>1.1 
        <div>1.1.1</div>
        <div>1.1.2</div>
    </div>
    <div>1.2 
        <div>1.2.1</div>
        <div>1.2.2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```